# Putting a table in Editing mode using a generic button instead of navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hi Im trying to build an app using larger buttons for those with disabilities and the standard Nav doesn't suit the App. How do I get the editing mode of a Table from a regular button from the Object Library.

I know the Nav bar items can do it very easily but Im trying to get the code to work off a generic button, Can anyone point me in the right direction,

Here is the following code Im Using using the Navitem Buttons,

```
    `

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
    var data:[String] = []
    var file:String!
    var text:String = ""

    @IBOutlet weak var noteText: UITextView!


    @IBAction func addNew(_ sender: UIButton) {
   addnote()
    }
    // original code
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        load()
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    // Notes section code
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func addnote(){
        let name:String = "Row \(data.count + 1)"
        data.insert(name, at: 0)
        let indexpath:IndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        table.insertRows(at: [indexpath], with: .automatic)
         self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "noteDetail", sender: nil)
        save()
    }

    // editing code button
    override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool){

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "noteDetail", sender: nil)
    }


    func tableView( _ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle:UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { data.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        table.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        save()

    }



    func save (){
        UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "notes")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }

    func load() {
        if let loadedData = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "notes") as? [String] {
            data = loadedData
            //table.reloadData()
        }
    }

    // Notes section code


    // Seques to move from each section on Home page
    @IBAction func remButton(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "remSeque", sender: self)
    }
    @IBAction func noteButton(_ sender: Any) {
         performSegue(withIdentifier: "noteSeque", sender: self)
    }
    @IBAction func reminderButton(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "reminderSeque", sender: self)
    }
    @IBAction func mapsButton(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "mapSeque", sender: self)
    }










    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

`

Comment: Could you be more specific and add some code you have been playing around with?

Comment: @FlorianLeitgeb  Please see above the code Im messing about with

Answer (score 3):

You should toggle the table view's `isEditing` property.

```
@IBAction func editButtonPressed() {
    tableView.isEditing = !tableView.isEditing
}
```

Comment: Hi @the4kman  Thank you for your answer, Im not sure on how to update this, Im very new to swift, please see my entire code above